# CGImage cropping doesn't give the specified rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, crop

I have a view where you can paint on. I save the minimal and maximal x and y touch-locations to specify the rectangle in which was painted. I tested, if the rectangle was right by adding a view with it as a frame, and everything worked fine. But when I am cropping the image to the rectangle, it gives me some other part.

```
guard let cg_img = self.asImage().cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(x: minX, y: minY, width: maxX-minX, height: maxY-minY)) else { return }
```

My asImage-method:

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I probably missed something about the cropping method, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: try `extension UIView {
    var image: UIImage {
        let imageRendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        imageRendererFormat.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: imageRendererFormat).image {
            layer.render(in: $0.cgContext) }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method to retrieve the `UIImage` from the `UIView` will return an image with the [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale) of the device. And your coordinates are likely in “points”. But `CGImage` coordinates are in pixels. You’ll have to convert your coordinates accordingly (by the scale of the image). E.g. if you’re on a @3x device, multiply these values by the `scale` of the original image before cropping.

---

This won’t be an issue for your screen snapshots, but for the sake of future readers, please note that the `CGRect` of the `CGImage` crop will be affected by the image rotation, e.g. portrait images captured by the camera. See [`imageOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624141-imageorientation). Bottom line, in addition to the `scale` issue noted earlier, also be aware that the `width` and `height` of the `CGImage` may be flipped from those of the `UIImage`.

Comment: multiplying all parameters for the rect with the device scale fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

after your

```
guard let cg_img = self.asImage().cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(x: minX, y: minY, width: maxX-minX, height: maxY-minY)) else { return }
```

just do this

```
let image = UIImage(cgImage: cg_img)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentMode = .center
imageView.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

to have the image in the right scale.